# AS3 Air On Android - Load SWF as its own Main()

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I'm using a wrapper app to download a remote SWF and save it to a Xoom Tablet. The download and save works fine but using something like

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("app.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest(file.url)/*,context needed?*/);
_main.addChild(loader);
```

Screws with the targeting in the loaded swf so that in my loaded swf if I try and call "stage" from "Main" its null. I thought since loaded SWF's had there own sandbox it would load and run just like it I installed it by its self, does not seem to be the case. If this was a desktop app I could use NativeWindow but its not supported on mobile devices yet. Are there any know options where I can load and run it in its own sandbox where paths and roots are intact? Possibly a command it launch it as a separate swf from my wrapper swf?

Comment: is `stage` called in the loaded swf `Main` constructor or inside of the `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` handler?

Comment: yes its called after the stage is live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into more issues but finaly found the correct way, you cant acceess "File" but this works just fine.

```
function getSWF():void
{
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("child.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadHandler);
loader.load(request);
_main.addChild(loader);// _main is my display sprite
}

function loadHandler(event:Event):void
{
   var childSwf:Object = event.target.content;
   childSwf.init( PARAMS );// in my case I needed to pass XML but this is any method in the Main of the child swf, note that "stage" is read only, so your parent swf needs to set any stage vars you need
}
```